# Clicking a single submit button submitting all the sitecore forms in the page

Tags: sitecore-forms

There are 5 sitecore forms in my page and 5 different custom submit actions for sending mail confirmation are configured for each sitecore form. But, clicking submit button on each form sending 5 mails instead of single relevant mail. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking the 'Is Ajax' field for the form worked!! Thanks